# Expression.Error There weren't enough elements in the enumeration to complete the operation. power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

Below is m code from power query (Excel 2016) for stock tickers.
If I enter proper tickers like MSFT it works perfectly but if I enter an incorrect ticker such as ddddddd I get the following error, "[Expression.Error] There weren't enough elements in the enumeration to complete the operation. "
How do I bypass this error and enter 0 for the value?
Can I use Try Otherwise somehow?

Thanks in advance!

```
(InputTicker as text) as table =>

let

Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&InputTicker&"/key-statistics?p="&InputTicker)),
    Data3 = Source{3}[Data],

#"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Data3),

#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Demoted Headers", each Text.Contains([Column1], "Forward Annual Dividend Yield"))
in

#"Filtered Rows"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 Data3 = try Source{3}[Data] otherwise #table({"First Column", "Second Column"}, {{"Forward Annual Dividend Yield",0}}),
```

Comment: Quick question. Where do I find the Source{3} in Excel? I couldn't find where it is located. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. I copied your code. Source{3} is the 4th row of the  table that comes back from your web query, and Source{3}[Data] is the contents of the table in the Data column in that row

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. I was playing around with "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT" in Power Query and selected different tables to see. The Source changed depending on which table I selected. Because I selected "Dividends and Splits" as the table, it was Source{3}.